# Integrating Netica with Python

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to access and use the Netica C API using Python.  While I can use ctypes windll to load the Netica.dll library, I'm having difficulty using the libraries functions since (it seems) many of them require a special data type for some inputs and outputs.

My base point for integrating Netica with Python is the wrapper provided here: https://publicwiki.deltares.nl/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=95158343

This wrapper uses ctypes to load in the Netica.dll and provides functions to access the functions in the .dll.

On the link provided above is an example for using the wrapper.  When I run this example, I get a "wrong type" error (described better below).  For the sake of discussion, consider the following code:

```py
from ctypes import *
netica = windll.LoadLibrary('Netica.dll')


# Create Netica Environment
netica.NewNeticaEnviron_ns.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_void_p, c_char_p]
netica.NewNeticaEnviron_ns.restype = c_void_p

env = netica.NewNeticaEnviron_ns(None, None, None) # (const char* license, environ_ns* env, const char* locn)

# Initialize Netica
mesg = create_string_buffer(300)
netica.InitNetica2_bn.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]
netica.InitNetica2_bn.restype = c_int

netica.InitNetica2_bn(env, mesg) # (environ_ns* env, char* mesg)

# Create New Network
netica.NewNet_bn.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_void_p]
netica.NewNet_bn.restype = c_void_p

net = netica.NewNet_bn('NewNetwork', env) # (const char* name, environ_ns* env)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

This suggests that the first argument of netica.NewNet_bn() is the wrong type even though it is a string and the arg type is defined as "c_char_p".

For reference, I've added in comments the datatypes the .dll functions are expecting.  Am I missing something concerning datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem.  Just need to encode the strings first using 'String'.encode('utf-8')

Comment: Or you could do: `net = netica.NewNet_bn(b'NewNetwork', env)`.